# pandas get multiple groupby results into the same table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`,

```
ccode    year_month    user    tcode
10       201903        WF      MI
10       201903        WF      MI
10       201903        QQ      MI
10       201903        QQ      MI 
20       201904        BATCH   MI
20       201904        WF      MI
20       201904        BATCH   MI
```

I like to do the following,

```
inv_tran_user_ccode_ym_gr_df = df.groupby(
        ['tcode', 'user', 'ccode', 'year_month']).size().reset_index(name='count')

    inv_tran_user_ccode_ym_gr_df['bus_unit_pct'] = inv_tran_user_ccode_ym_gr_df['count'].div(
        inv_tran_user_ccode_ym_gr_df.groupby(['ccode', 'year_month'])['count'].transform('sum')).mul(
        100).round(2)

    inv_tran_user_ym_gr_df = df.groupby(
        ['tcode', 'user', 'year_month']).size().reset_index(name='count')

    inv_tran_user_ym_gr_df['org_pct'] = inv_tran_user_ym_gr_df['count'].div(
        inv_tran_user_ym_gr_df.groupby(['year_month'])['count'].transform('sum')).mul(
        100).round(2)
```

I am wondering is it possible to make `org_pct` and `bus_unit_pct` into the same table.

```
ccode    year_month    user    tcode    org_pct    bus_unit_pct
10       201903        WF      MI       50%        50%
10       201903        QQ      MI       50%        50%
20       201904        WF      MI       33%        33%
20       201904        BATCH   MI       67%        67%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done all the hard work. It's a relatively simple `merge` from here:

```py
(inv_tran_user_ccode_ym_gr_df.drop('count', axis=1)
                            .merge(inv_tran_user_ym_gr_df.drop('count', axis=1),
                                   on=['year_month', 'user', 'tcode']))
```

resulting in

```
  tcode   user  ccode  year_month  bus_unit_pct  org_pct
0    MI  BATCH     20      201904         66.67    66.67
1    MI     QQ     10      201903         50.00    50.00
2    MI     WF     10      201903         50.00    50.00
3    MI     WF     20      201904         33.33    33.33
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply merge the two datasets together.

```
result = pd.merge(inv_tran_user_ccode_ym_gr_df, inv_tran_user_ym_gr_df, on=['tcode','user','year_month'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the original df, you can also try with `groupby` then `value_counts` with `normalize=True`:
Per docs:

> If True then the object returned will contain the relative frequencies of the unique values.

```
(df.groupby(['ccode','year_month','tcode'])['user'].value_counts(normalize=True)
 .mul(100).round(2).reset_index(name='bus_unit_pct').rename(columns={'level_3':'user'}))
```

---

```
   ccode  year_month tcode   user  bus_unit_pct
0     10      201903    MI     QQ         50.00
1     10      201903    MI     WF         50.00
2     20      201904    MI  BATCH         66.67
3     20      201904    MI     WF         33.33
```